# How can I convert WriteableBitmap to BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("arka_projects_as_logo.png", UriKind.Relative));
Image uiElement = new Image() { Source = bitmapImage };
ScaleTransform t = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = 0.2, ScaleY = 0.2 };
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(uiElement,t);
```

I want to insert the result of this conversions (writeableBitmap) into System.Windows.Controls.Image. When I do this:

```
Image arkaImage = new Image() { Source = writeableBitmap };
```

`arkaImage` isn't shown at all. What can be done to make it work?

Answer (score 10):

```
WriteableBitmap wb = ..
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)image1.Width, (int)image1.Height, 0, 100);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(ms);
}
```

Comment: there is no SaveJpeg in WriteableBitmap

Comment: @Nayef: it's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in another namespace.

Comment: How to use it? I tried to include it but I couldn't do in Silverlight, any idea?

Comment: @abatishchev your link is broken - is this the same [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg) you were referencing? in which case the extensions class only build for windows phone platforms now it seems

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just apply the `ScaleTransform` to the `UIElement` as well?